# CSS Sticky Footer on a Wordpress Page without Content Div

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I'm trying to make my footer going down to the end of the page so that it sticks to the bottom.

I tried using a tutorial where I used that css styles to make the footer sticky to the bottom:

```
    * { margin:0; padding:0; } 

html, body, #wrap { height: 100%; }

body > #wrap {height: auto; min-height: 100%;}

#main { padding-bottom: 175px; }  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {
        position: relative;
    margin-top: -175px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 175px;
    clear:both;} 

/* CLEAR FIX*/
.clearfix:after {content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;}
.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
```

I'm trying to make that work now for hours, could someone please check on my problem ?

[My project I'm working on](http://iflorian.com/fwb_new/wordpress/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the sticky footer effect you have to make some modifications to your HTML and CSS, try the following:

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#colophon:before, #colophon:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    zoom:1; /*ie fix*/
}
#colophon:after {
    clear: both;
}
footer {
    display: block;
}

#page {
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 2em auto -175px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

In order for your footer to stick to the bottom you have to separate it from your `#page` container, like so:

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed">..</div>
<footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">...</footer>
```

And that should do the trick!

Comment: Thank you sooo much! You saved my day ;) That's what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

its more simple than what you are doing. try this structure

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="centering-div">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That way the footer content will always be on the bottom. you can add css styles to the centering-div id to give site width and centering css. You shouldn't need to specify positioning on the sections of a page that span the entire width. within the content div is where you should put all your content.

Comment: That can't be the easiest way, as I wrote I'm using Wordpress and therefore it would be really really hard to change my theme and wordpress to work that way.

Comment: I just looked at your page's source code and its the same structure. The only difference is instead of using div's its using footer elements. So, in your css, there is no id of footer so css should just be footer{}. Try taking out all that positioning css as the elements are already in the correct positions for your site. you only need to apply the clear:both fix on elements right after others that use some sort of float positioning to bring them down on the next level.